# moto for python - write to sqs fails

Tags: python, boto3, amazon-sqs, python-unittest, moto

i have a method in my code that sends message to a sqs. i want to use moto and use the aws sqs service.

Below is my code

```
 def posttosqs(self,url,body):
    try:

        sqs_cli = boto3.client('sqs')
        sqs_cli.send_message(QueueUrl=url, MessageBody=body)
    except Exception as e:

        raise Exception("Posting failed to SQS")
```

here is my test case

```
    @mock_sqs
    @mock_s3
    def test_case_use_moto(self):

        conn = boto3.resource('s3', region_name='us-east-1')
        conn.create_bucket(Bucket='Test')
        conn = boto3.client('sqs', region_name='us-east-1')
        queue = conn.create_queue(QueueName='Test')

        os.environ["SQS_URL"] = queue["QueueUrl"]
        conn.send_message(QueueUrl=queue["QueueUrl"], MessageBody="test") #this works
        #SQS_URL = "https://queue.amazonaws.com/123456789012/Test"
        ctx = context_class_object()
        event = {"body": "test"}
        resp = lambda.handle_request(event, ctx)
        assert resp["statusCode"] == 200
```

the `conn.send_message` works in the test case but the method `posttosqs` fails with

`error: when calling the SendMessage operation: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.`

I was able to test the S3 operations successfully using above method but not SQS operation

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Installing specific moto version worked for me, the issue is with newer versions of moto library.

```
pip install moto==2.2.2
```